# Swing java вывод окон после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: java, swing, button

Я сделал прогу, она выводит окно с 4 кнопками. Как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на любую их них, выводилось другое окно (`JFrame`)?
Вот код:

```
public class InterfaceCalq extends JFrame {
    JButton button0 = new JButton("1");
    JButton button1 = new JButton("2");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("3");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("4");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public InterfaceCalq() {
            super("Калькулятор по-формулам");
            this.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            panel.add(button0);
            panel.add(button1);
            panel.add(button2);
            panel.add(button3);
            this.add(panel);
        }
        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InterfaceCalq inter = new InterfaceCalq();
        inter.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
button0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(100,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```